# Ruby: if variable vs if variable.nil?

Tags: coding-style, ruby, null

I'm new to Ruby and I was surprised when I found out that all objects are true apart from nil and false. Even 0 is true.

A nice thing about that property of the language is that you can write:

```
if !variable
  # do stuff when variable is nil
end
```

My colleagues, who are more seasoned Ruby developers, insist I should choose that instead of using .nil? like so:

```
if variable.nil?
  # do stuff when variable is nil
end
```

However I believe that the latter is a better option for two reasons:
1. I think it's more object oriented, especially in a language like Ruby where everything is an object and message exchange.
2. It is more readable, in my subject opinion, even if it is less compact.

Am I making a "newbie" mistake here?

Comment: Are you testing for nil? or a false value?

Comment: I'm testing for nil. Basically if the variable is nil, I do something (or not)

Comment: If you are testing for nil, why do you want the test for false to also enter that block?

Comment: Agree, I pointed that out as another reason to prefer .nil? But they insisted that "if variable do x" is more idiomatic than "if variable.nil? do x" and preferable when you know that variable is not boolean

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Write what you mean. Mean what you write.

Lets take a different test.  `.vowel?`

```
if char == 'a'
   # do stuff
end
```

vs

```
if char.vowel?
   # do stuff
end
```

Now, its obvious that these do not do the same thing.  But if you're only expecting `char` to be `a` or `b` it will work.  But it will confuse the next developer - the second block will be entered into for the conditions where char is `[eiou]` also.  But for `a`, it will work correctly.

Yes, it is the case that `nil` and `false` are the only falsy values in Ruby. However, if you are testing for `nil` by testing for `nil || false`, this isn't what you mean.

It means that the next developer (who happens to be a crazy axe murder who knows your home address) will read the code, and wonder why `false` should go in there too.

Write the code that conveys ***exactly*** what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following:

`response = responses.to_a.first`

This will return the first element of `responses`, or `nil`. Then because conditional statements treat `nil` as `false` we can write:

```
response = responses.to_a.first
if response
  # do something ('happy path')
else
  # do something else
end
```

Which is more readable than:

```
if response.nil?
  # do something else
else
  # do something ('happy path')
end
```

The `if (object)` pattern is very common in Ruby code. It also leads nicely to refactoring, e.g.:

```
if response = responses.to_a.first
  do_something_with(response)
else
  # response is equal to nil
end
```

Remember also that a Ruby method returns `nil` by default. So:

```
def initial_response
  if @condition
    @responses.to_a.first
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

can be simplified to:

```
def initial_response
  if @condition
    @responses.to_a.first
  end
end
```

So we can further refactor:

```
if response = initial_response
  do_something_with(response)
else
  # response is equal to nil
end
```

Now you can argue that returning `nil` is not always the best idea, since it means checking for `nil` everywhere. But that is another kettle of fish. Given that testing for object "presence or absence" is such a frequent requirement, the truthiness of objects is a useful aspect of Ruby, albeit surprising for newcomers to the language.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is `if variable.nil?` read more like natural language, it also guards against a programmer accidentally assigning it a `false` value and falling into your `if` statement, since Ruby is a loosely typed language.

Comment: So the initial comment in the original question was wrong? Should have been "do stuff when variable is nil or false"? And since code not matching comment is a bug, there's a bug straight away?

Comment: Correct. A simple truthiness test could introduce logic errors.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, `unless variable` is preferable to `if !variable`. Negated `if` statements are often considered a code smell as it's easier to miss the negation when skimming.

The bigger picture here is that doing `nil` checks like this is also a bit of a code smell. For proper OO, aim to use [the null object pattern](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) so that this sort of check is never needed.

Tell objects what to do, don't ask them what they are. This is sometimes known as [tell don't ask](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask)